# How to remove the left over lines after cutting

Tags: neovim

how do I cut text in vim and automatically remove the remaining lines. For example, when I cut the following text using `d`:

[image]

The lines remain there:

[image]

But I want to remove those lines with the cut. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) I suppose we need a bit more context to help you. I don't see the `<style>` tags in the first screen shot. I suppose they are before and after the section you have selected. How did you select the code? Using `Ctrl- v`, using `Shift-v` or using `v`?

Comment: Yeah the style tags are there, I just didn't screenshot properly haha. I used B-Visual mode (Ctrl-V) to highlight the text. Thanks for the welcome :)!

And now I am seeing that using SHIFT-V to cut removes the remaining spaces. So thanks for answering my question indirectly! Altho kinda curious as to why it doesn't with B-Visual?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the lines to be deleted when you run the `d` command I suggest you to select the lines in `visual` mode (that you start with <kbd>v</kbd>) or in `visual line` mode (that you start with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>).

If you select `visual block' mode (that you start with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>) the lines will not be deleted.